# 4-20mA output/transmitter?

Tags: dac, 4-20ma

I've got an MCU with a 3.3V DAC onboard and I'd like to convert the 0-3.3V signal to a 4-20mA output. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: How About using a mosfet transistor?, keep in mind they are not linear, so you will have to look at the data-sheet of your mosfet. You can also use op-amps I Googled `voltage to current converter using op amp` and there are lots of solutions.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/xtr300.pdf

Comment: is this to interface with other 4-20mA circuitry?  Such a std is usually terminated by a 50->750R resistor thus 1V --> 15V at the termination end THUS higher at the transmission end.

Comment: I'm well aware of the **hundreds** of parts from TI, Analog Devices, and others. What I'm not clear on is if any part that takes a 3V3 analog input as full-scale input, nor am I clear on if this is the best approach/should I do something else/is there a trick.

Comment: I Googled this too... There is no published data on what the stability/full-scale deviation of the signal is when put through an op-amp circuit. Any idea if this type of info or an application note for this style of converter is published?

Comment: It's a lot easier to convert 0 - 3.3v to 0mA-20mA. Have you considered using an offset in the DAC to give you the 4mA or are you struggling for resolution?

Comment: This question is NOT off topic. It specifically FITS the requirements as stated in the help page. I quote from the Help > Asking section: "but if your question generally covers …

**a specific electronics design problem**
the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
**a communication scheme**
the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @Andyaka Frankly it would be a good thing to be able to output 0-20 as well, but 4-20 will do.

Comment: @Naib I understand there is resistance in the cable... are you saying that the transmitter needs to output more than 20mA? I'm aware that most devices include trim pots so the signal can be calibrated at each device in the loop, so I don't know how much of an issue this is.

Comment: I am asking are you planning on interfacing with other 4-20mA systems. Its an industrial standard AND at the reciever end there is a terminating resistor (that can be 50 --> 750R). Now most industrial tranducers are around 30V so they have plenty of headroom to drive 20mA through a 750R system as well as any cable impedance.  Right now you would not be able to interface to a system terminated by 120R

Comment: Look for a constant current circuit that uses an opamp, a bipolar transistor and an emitter resistor. The opamp feedback loop ensures that the current through the resistor equals Vin / R. I don't know why the question was put on hold.

Comment: @Naib I don't think I understand what you mean. I do intend to interface with other 4-20 systems but I'm not sure what you mean by terminating resistor... I'm aware of using a resistor to convert the current signal to voltage for use with an ADC but I don't know what you mean by what you wrote. Why would I not be able to interface with a 120R terminated system and what does this mean? According to my math/Ohm's law, a 120R with 20mA current would give us a max output voltage of 2.4V on the receiving device in the loop... what does this have to do with anything? Please explain.

Comment: @Andyaka neither do I. I think someone got butt hurt because they chose to call my question stupid and I explained that it is quite valid.

Comment: @Pugz - hey it's not that valid dude - consider this - should the constant current driver work relative to 0V i.e. should it "consume" the 4-20mA from resistor tied up to some arbitrary higher voltage or, should it source current to a resistor tied to ground (in which case it might need a power supply of 6V minimum (or thereabouts). You've got to think how this works - a lot of "current receivers" also work through a bridge rectifier to ensure current is going in the correct direction. Maybe you ought to start a new question and try sketch out a block diagram.

Comment: @pugz basically... is 3v3 the only voltage you have available or can at least get upto 15V on the setup?

Comment: Seriously. WHY WAS THIS QUESTION CLOSED!? Other people even said they couldn't tell why it was put on hold. Please open this back up! It is a valid question as I explained and I don't appreciate being shut out for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the ICs called "voltage to current" converters and follow one of the appnotes or datasheet examples to achieve your goal. You get a lot with them, but of course you pay in terms of cost and single-source.

A way is to use a +V power source to provide whatever voltage compliance you want (with an output impedance of some kind, usually sized larger for perhaps a watt or more) and a BJT to sink current to ground. In the emitter leg of the BJT, there is a current measuring resistor that develops a ground-referenced voltage that is used to feed back to an opamp that is driving the BJT. But you need to worry about oscillation and perhaps calibration with offset and gain adjustments. Often, that is handled by using a dual op-amp package like the cheap and decent TL062A, with one of the opamps accepting the voltage input and providing offset and gain adjustments and the other opamp doing the current monitoring and driving the BJT sink.

You haven't said a word about the necessary voltage compliance for the 4-20mA output. Nor the specific MCU and the characteristics of the DAC (like its precision, for example, let alone output characteristics.) Nor what kind of accuracy you need and whether or not you care about offset errors and/or gain errors, differential or integral linearity, etc.

Also, what have you googled and rejected?

Comment: DAC is 12-bit on the MCU. Loop V needs to be between 9 and 36V. I do need this to be VERY linear. The output must have as little variance in linearity as possibly. As I stated in another comment, I don't know "what the stability/full-scale deviation of the signal is when put through an op-amp circuit" and can't really find any info on it, though if it's like a many circuits made from discrete components I fear it might be to bad for what I need. I've looked at devices such as the TI DAC8760 which uses SPI in and can output 4-20 and 0-10V and take a 3V3 reference... just so expensive ($10/each)

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is - I don't care if I use the onboard DAC if it's too much trouble. I'm fine with a discrete DAC that can do 4-20 if it works better.

Comment: I think you need to pay the price. I don't know what "very linear" means, but if you want top quality and can't do the design then you need to buy one of those expensive devices with specs you can read about and support staff who can help make sure you use it right. I suppose that is where some of the money goes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [XTR115 by TI](http://www.ti.com/product/xtr115). Or you could skip the D-A step and get a digital 4-20 driver like the [AD421 by Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/digital-to-analog-converters/da-converters/ad421/products/product.html). There are newer ones but those are 2 I've used in the past.

Comment: I called TI about this part today, and the others in the XTR family... I'm still not clear on whether they take 3.3V as full scale input/how the reference works. He did say these parts are legacy... most of the XTRs were released around 2000.

Comment: From what I can tell, the XTRs require a 5V analog input voltage reference and can't do 3.3.

Comment: XTR is a current amplifier.No voltage reference is needed you get 100X current on output.